# Multiple Rewrite Rules, Try A then B

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following directory structure:

```
root
--/inc
--/img
--/docs
---/public
----/contact
-----/img
------telephone.jpg
-----contact.php
---/private
```

My aim is to make each folder under 'docs' a 'contained' webpage.  Each folder will have it's own `/img/` folder, and a `/bin/` folder too, which could contain anything from Mp3s to PDFs.

Currently I am routing everything through to index.php, and then manually redirecting the file from there.  But this is proving to be very slow.  What I was thinking would be faster would be something like this in my .htaccess if say, an image was trying to be accessed via `/contact/telephone.png`:

```
try /img/{url_path}
Otherwise, try /docs/$1/img/$2
Otherwise route through index.php
```

How could I go about doing this? Currently my .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# if file not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# if dir not exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# avoid 404s of missing assets in our script
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(jpe?g|png|gif|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if this image path exists in docs/<folder>/img first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/docs/$1/img/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)/?$ /docs/$1/img/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Just a thought, but as /img/ is an actual directory, surley I do not need a rule for that?

Comment: Also, in /docs/ there is an /img/ folder that it needs to look in, this doesnt seem to be in your code above?

Comment: Is your URI always in form of `/contact/telephone.png` i.e. `/<some-path>/<img-name>`?

Comment: Yes it is.  Would this work: `RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_]+)/([a-zA-Z_]+)$ /docs/$1/img/$2 [L,NC,NE]`

Comment: ok check the update. Since you're asking `try A then try B` we need to apply sort of `if/elseif/elseif/else` logic by using conditions `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/docs/$1/img/$2 -f`